# Custom JQueryUI ValidationMessageFor hide validation extension method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I've been working on creating a custom error validation message for MVC that displays the error message jQueryUI style.

Looks cool so far but I need to hide the entire div when there is no error message...how do I do this?

Here is my html helper extension method:

```
  public static MvcHtmlString MyValidationMessageFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {              
                TagBuilder widgetDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
                widgetDiv.AddCssClass("ui-widget");
                widgetDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "font-size: 10px");

                TagBuilder errorDiv = new TagBuilder("div");
                errorDiv.AddCssClass("ui-state-error ui-corner-all");
                errorDiv.Attributes.Add("style", "padding:0 .7em;");

                TagBuilder paragraph = new TagBuilder("p");

                TagBuilder span = new TagBuilder("span");
                span.AddCssClass("ui-icon ui-icon-alert");
                span.Attributes.Add("style", "float: left; margin-right: .3em;");

                TagBuilder strong = new TagBuilder("strong");
                strong.InnerHtml = "Alert: ";

                paragraph.InnerHtml += span.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
                paragraph.InnerHtml += strong.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);
                paragraph.InnerHtml += helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString();           

                errorDiv.InnerHtml += paragraph.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);

                widgetDiv.InnerHtml += errorDiv.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal);                               

                return MvcHtmlString.Create(widgetDiv.ToString(TagRenderMode.Normal));            
        }
```

And here is the html it produces:

```
 <div class="ui-widget">
    <div class="ui-state-error ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0 .7em;">
        <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float: left; margin-right: .3em;"></span>
        <strong>Alert:</strong> Sample ui-state-error style.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm assuming I need to return a blank string according to some condition...how do I do this?

Edit: Added picture to illustrate problem - the div displays with empty text regardless.

[image: Alert!]

Edit2: I noticed that when debugging this method is only hit once...maybe unobtrusive validation is the problem.

This code didn't help:

```
string propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
string name = helper.AttributeEncode(helper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName));

if (helper.ViewData.ModelState[name] == null ||
    helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors == null ||
    helper.ViewData.ModelState[name].Errors.Count == 0)
{
    return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do a test on the validation message before constructing the HTML block? If it's empty then there is no error.

```
var validationMessage = helper.ValidationMessageFor(expression).ToString();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage))
{
    // Build your message as in your code.
}
```

Comment: validationMessage == "<span class=\"field-validation-valid\" data-valmsg-for=\"UserName\" data-valmsg-replace=\"true\"></span>" so that won't work. I've also noticed that a breakpoint on that method is only hit once (I'm using unobtrusive validation)...maybe its not possible through the extension method.

Comment: Well if you are getting an empty span you could check that pretty easily with a regex. It's not very elegant though...

Comment: I did some homework... If you have a copy of "Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 Framework" kicking around, starting on page 636 it explains how to do what you are trying to do. It is a good bit of work, and involves creating custom attributes that implement `IClientValidatable` and working them in with jQuery. It is quite a bit of work, however, and custom attributes for each message might be undesirable from an architectural point of view. Can you not make the changes you want to the messages by changing the CSS of the built-in validation messages?

Comment: Yeah we have a copy of Steve Sandersons book at work - I'll check it out. I wanted to avoid custom attributes if possible. I'd looked at the built in css for validation but unfortunately by changing that I won't be able to add in the error icon. Thanks for the help though :)

Comment: Icon eh... what about as a background image?

Comment: may work...ill fiddle and see if I can come up with something. I have it working fine for the ValidationSummary now so I might just use the standard ValidationMessageFor. <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert">

Comment: I've done this before and it works alright... you need to specify the position of your background image as shifted in that direction and then give yourself some padding on that side to compensate so that other elements don't invade the image's space.

Comment: used something like this for now:   .field-validation-error
{
    color: #06377d;      
    background-image: url(images/exclamation.png);         
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    padding-left:16px;
}

Comment: That's how I would go about it honestly. Hope that works for you.